# Does HttpUrlConnection censor some headers, notably Origin?

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to create some tests for a web services that implements CORS. So, I need to send Origin headers. When I call `addRequestProperty("origin", origin)`, the origin header does not seem to appear at the server. I say 'seem' -- I'm got a servlet iterating over all the headers printing them out, and it does not appear. I haven't gone all the way to TCPMon or sending the request over a plain socket connection.

The javadoc for HttpUrlConnection doesn't mention any limits that I've seen, but I might have skipped a critical sentence. Is this a well-known limitation?

Comment: What webserver are you running your servlet in? Are there any proxies, or other webservers inbetween?

Comment: Are you setting 'origin' or 'Origin'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#L189

The author, cleverly, decided to forbid Origin and other CORS-related headers without actually implementing the CORS spec. It's pretty depressing.

Comment: looking at that code, you can use the `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders` system property to enable setting these headers.

Comment: Yes, but only if you are willing to set it before you get your first connection and never change it. Luckily, the Apache HttpClient is a solution.

Comment: The link provided is no longer valid. For reference, here is an updated link to [one of the relevant lines](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#235) at grepcode.

Comment: It is really depressing to see that CORS headers has been restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use Apache HTTP Client to use the CORS headers. And now it works as expected.