# Java JSOUP how to send the Origin in the header

Tags: java, http, cors, jsoup

im trying to test my service using JSOUP, but i'm using CORS, and i need to send
the origin only for test porpouses, but when i send this i'dont receive on the server side, always receive null.

```
Connection con = Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:8080/myservice");
 con.userAgent("Mozilla");
 /* the origin is replaced to null automatically*/
 con.header("Origin", origin);
 con.ignoreHttpErrors(true);
 con.followRedirects(true);
 con.ignoreContentType(true);
 con.post();
```

I would do something diferent of this?

SOLVED:

Use ApacheHTTP instead JSOUP, cause JSOUP remove the Origin header by default.
:)

Comment: is origin an actual variable?

Comment: Yes, sorry. String origin = "http://localhost:8080";

Comment: try addHeader instead? https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Base.html#addHeader-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: Don't have this method addHeader, have only header(String, String) to put the header, another headers work, only Origin doesnt work.

Comment: Could be that origin headers are meant to have a protocol, try http://localhost:8080 instead?

Comment: Solved using Apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes, JSoup is using a `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to make the connection.  `HttpURLConnection` has a set of restricted headers, including "Origin".  These don't seem to be well documented, but can be clearly seen in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.0restrictedHeaders).

As you mention using HttpClient will side step the problem.

Alternatively, to continue with a direct connection from JSoup, depending what else is happening in your environment, it may be an option to set the `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders` system property.  This can be seen further down in the source linked above.

This will bypass the header checking in `HttpURLConnection`, but annoyingly it is coded as a shared static value.  This means the system property will need to be set before the first connection is made anywhere in the JVM - e.g. as a `-D` command line option.

There more about this topic [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335501/does-httpurlconnection-censor-some-headers-notably-origin?rq=1).

Digressing slightly, the comment in the `HttpURLConnection` source, comparing the restricted headers there to `XMLHttpRequest2` is interesting - as if this is expecting to be run in a browser.  This restriction may date back to the days of Java applets?  It's perhaps less helpful now for server side applications.